# Realign Pandas Rolling Average series in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, average

Very new to Pandas.  Importing stock data in a DF and I want to calculate 10D rolling average. That I can figure out.   Issue is it gives 9 NaN because of the 10D moving average period.

I want to re-align the data so the 10th piece of data is a new rolling average column at the top of the data frame.  I tried moving the data by writing the following code:

```
small = pd.rolling_mean(df['Close'],10)
```

and then trying to add that to the df with the following code

```
df['MA10D2'] = small[9:]
```

but it still provides 9 NaN at the top.  Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Assignment will be done based on index. `small[9:]` will start the index at position 9, thus the assignement will keep their position starting at index 9.

The function you are searching for is called `shift`:

```
df['MA10D2'] = small.shift(-9)
```